# using Threading in for loop of ArrayList from a method

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I have a ArrayList  [big one read from a file] And I want to read its contents with multithreading and process each string calling a method repeatedly and printing it to a file .I have given a working structure of what my the code looks like.. How ever I a not able to code for what I want without getting tangled in exceptions related to synchronizations of threads ...
I am new to the concept of threading .. and want a efficient way to to this ..I have looked at other solutions related to threading and arraylists but it hasn't worked out for me .. any suggestions as to how to go about this is appreciated

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class threadingWithMathod {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        ArrayList<String> samples=readurls("path/to/sample.csv");
        PrintStream filewriter = new PrintStream(new File("path/to/result.csv"), "UTF-8");
        for (int i = 0; i < samples.size(); i++) {
            String string1 = samples.get(i);
            String string2 = samples.get(i+1);
            ///Need Info As to how process with Threading without clashing
            /// sampleProcessString need to be called repeatedly
            //sampleProcessString(filewriter,string) by 2-3 threads
        }
    }
    
    public static void sampleProcessString(PrintStream filewriter,String string) {
        filewriter.println(processedString(string));
    }
    private static Object processedString(String string) {
        //Intended to generate a new line by using a Sql query
        //This method will be using a connection to a mysql data base based on sample
        return string+"++> done something";
    }
    public static ArrayList<String> readurls(String filename) {
        ArrayList<String> aslink=new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( filename));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                    aslink.add(line);   
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return aslink;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have look into [concurrent collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html), for example [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). That way you can decouple File I/O from your processing threads.

Comment: Technically it's possible to write lines into a file from multiple threads, but their order will become mixed up, are you aware of that? On a side note, you may find working with streams both simpler and a better fit for this task.

Comment: ^^ [java.util.stream package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Comment: @tevemadar .. I don't mind if the order is mixed ... I just want the data of the arraylist processed

Comment: @Joop Eggen thanks your approach really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created some snippets where you can try dropping your actual processing code into.

My test data looks like this:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("testdata.txt")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        pw.println(i);
}
```

So a textfile with a million numbers in its lines.
My "task" was to create a file containing double the value of the same lines, disregarding their order:

```
pw.println(Integer.parseInt(line) * 2);
```

where `line` is a line from the input file, and `pw` is a `PrintWriter` for the output.
In actual code:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("testresult.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testdata.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        pw.println(Integer.parseInt(line) * 2);
}
```

This is something which can be written shorter, and perhaps a bit more readable with streaming:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("testresult.txt")) {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("testdata.txt")).forEach(
        line -> pw.println(Integer.parseInt(line) * 2));
}
```

The two snippets produce very similar execution times, around 1.6-1.7 seconds on my machine (measured with the "budget" approach, `long start = System.currentTimeMillis();` before and `System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);` after).

Then the stream can be parallelized with a single `.parallel()` inside:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("testresult.txt")) {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("testdata.txt")).parallel().forEach(
        line -> pw.println(Integer.parseInt(line) * 2));
}
```

This will produce mixed order results.
A side remark on `println(int)`: it's not documented, but its actual implementation is [thread-safe](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintWriter.java#l749), however if you want to be absolutely "safe" and build on the documented features only, you should synchronize it yourself:

```
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("testresult.txt")) {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("testdata.txt")).parallel().forEach(line -> {
        synchronized (pw) {
            pw.println(Integer.parseInt(line) * 2);
        }
    });
}
```

Both of them are actually slower than the sequential (2 and 2.2 seconds, the extra manual synchronization does matter), but of course it matters a lot that this processing step is very simple. So it's important to keep in mind that if file operations eat up the time in your case too, parallelism can not really help that.

And for comparison, a complete snippet using a thread pool:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
ExecutorCompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(es);
int counter=0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testdata.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        final String current = line;
        ecs.submit(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(current)*2);
            }
        });
        counter++;
    }
}
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("testresult.txt")) {
    while(counter>0) {
        pw.println(ecs.take().get());
        counter--;
    }
}
es.shutdown();
```

This one is the longest of them for sure, on the other hand it runs for 2 seconds, so comparable to the `synchronized`-less streaming sample, and it's "safe" without it as file operations all happen in the main thread (workers only calculate and stringify). Going for full-manual threads could make things even more verbose, but I don't feel motivated to write such code at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a large file is fastest done sequentially, because of the physical disk access.
One might use memory mapped byte buffers.
In your case (processing per line) [`Files.lines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) (default UTF-8) may suffice.

This is *fine grained* concurrency. The processing may be done in parallel by using a thread pool, ExecutorService, [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), as there will come in *many* threads.

You will get the results out of order. If that is a problem, pass a line number in `Files.lines`' lambda.

For collecting the results, queing them in memory and asynchroneously writing them to file, one could look whether there is a high-performance logger. Probably one has to
reimplement its functionality (to do away with log formatting). So a queuing thread and a thread for writing to file (a large byte buffer).

One might consider compressing the output (.csv.gz); which would be a space/time-gain on further network transport.

---

There are many ways of realizing this, so research javadoc and variations (FutureTask for instance) and look into examples.

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);       
    for (;;)  {
        Task task = new Task(...);
         executor.execute(task);
    }
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) { ... }
    executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks for the  your suggestion regarding Files.lines(Paths) for large files.. I'll be implementing this and  also the logger idea  ...Please can you give a rough snippet of how "using a thread pool, ExecutorService, ThreadPoolExecutor, as there will come in many threads."  can be implemented here ...

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/ will be more interesting than a code example I have added.

Comment: By the way I would start with a dumb implementation to time say 10 000 lines, and then check the gain with an optimized version. It is not unheard one is optimizing the wrong part, and even makes things slower, the application unresponsive. Also it is nice to know the speed gain in exact numbers.